# Populate UITableView with nested JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, json, uitableview

as the title suggest I'm trying to populate a UITableView from JSON. I get the json object which looks like

```
  {
    applications: {
           iphone: {
             application: [
                            {
                              title: "Title",
                             },
                             {
                              title: "Title2",
                             },
                             {
                              title: "Title3",
                             }
                           ]
                      }
                     }
    }
```

it goes on like that, with several `title` fields nested inside of application.

I would like to use all the titles as my cell labels.
I can get a list like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        titleString = [[[[[result objectForKey:@"applications"] objectForKey:@"iphone"] objectForKey:@"application"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"title %@", titleString);
    }
```

which does work, as in I can log the list of titles...but I know I'm going about this in the wrong way, I can't even figure out what myArray would be in the `return [myArray count]` in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method... totally lost here! help is appreciated!

Comment: Your json object looks incomplete.

Comment: that's true, because I cut it off, just for clarity's sake. I successfully retrieve the JSON in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[[result objectForKey:@"applications"] objectForKey:@"iphone"] objectForKey:@"application"]` is going to return array, so better store this array and use it wherever is required as follows:

```
NSArray *titleArray = [[[result objectForKey:@"applications"] objectForKey:@"iphone"] objectForKey:@"application"];
```

To store this array you can use instance variable so that you can use it entire file.

Answer (score 0):

You can store these titles in an array then use this array as datasource for the table. Your myArray would be the array your stored titles in.

Answer (score 0):

First is Application dictionary
this Application dictionary has one dictionary of key iPhone
this iphoneDic has an array of Dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary *applicationsDict = [response objectForKey:@"applications"];
NSMutableDictionary *iphoneDict = [applicationsDict objectForKey:@"iphone"];
NSMutableArray *applicationArray = [iphoneDict objectForKey:@"application"];
```

now in the method numberOfRowInSection: of table view return the array count

```
return [applicationArray count]
```

now in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: mthod we will use this applicationArray
Use Array ...

```
NSMutableDictionary *titleDict = [applicationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.titleLabel.text = [titleDict objectForKey:@"title"];
```

I hope this will help you